# Slater determinant as (zero order) approximation to Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, identical-particles

I understand how the Slater determinant for N particle works and its application in writing an antisymmetric wavefunction. However the question asks me to show that the Slater determinant is a zero order approximation to Schrodinger equation for N identical (non interacting) fermions and I can't seem to find a way to solve this problem.

How exactly are these seemingly distinct concepts related?

Comment: What do you mean by 'a zero order approximation to Schrodinger equation for N identical (non interacting) fermions'?

Comment: @Jakob: Here's what the exact problem says: "Show that the Slater determinant is a zero-order approximation to the Schrödinger equation
of a system of N identical (non interacting) fermions."  And this is why I am stumped too, like these seem vastly different concepts :(